# Why does the ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor considers only one PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

The `ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor` is used whenever a bean is annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties` in order to bind property values to a bean.

The implementation of `ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor` (Spring Boot version 1.3.1) determines its property sources in the method `deducePropertySources()` as shown below:

```
private PropertySources deducePropertySources() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = getSinglePropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    if (configurer != null) {
        // Flatten the sources into a single list so they can be iterated
        return new FlatPropertySources(configurer.getAppliedPropertySources());
    }
    ...
}
```

When looking into `getSinglePropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer()` you'll discover that only the first `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` is taken and the others are ignored.

What is the reason for this?
In my Spring configuration I have multiple `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` beans and I would expect that all of them are used when binding the property values.

Of course I can create a workaround by defining an interface `MyPropertySourceResources` that looks like this:

```
public interface MyPropertySourceResources {

    List<Resource> getResources();

}
```

and in my Spring configuration I define only one `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` that takes a list of  `MyResourceLocartion` as parameter:

```
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer gdaPropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer(
                List<MyPropertySourceResources> propertySourceResources) {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    List<Resource> allResources = propertySourceResources.stream()
                    .flatMap(p -> p.getResources().stream())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
    propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocations(allResources.toArray(new Resource[allResources.size()]));
    return propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
}

@Bean
public MyPropertySourceResources gdaPropertySourceResources() {
    return () -> Arrays.asList(new FileSystemResource(new File("path/to/my.properties")));
}
```

In this solution each module defines its own `MyPropertySourceResources` bean and all of them will be used to build up the only `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.

But back to my question: Is there a good reason why the `ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor` takes only one `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` into account?

Comment: Because context dose not need another PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer instances. One is enough to replace placeholders with value. Possible, you question should be: "Why Spring context does not merge multiple PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer instances?"....